# Determine the list separator of the system

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to Access & VBA, so please excuse me if my question is silly. However, I was wondering if there is a way to check/display (maybe even with MsgBox) what is the default list separator on the computer that the access file has been opened? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `MsgBox Application.International(xlListSeparator)`.

Comment: `Application.International` doesn't seem to be available in Access VBA, but you could launch an Excel Application object and get it from there.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I really appreciate it. Frankly, I was secretly hoping for an easier solution. Earlier while researching the topic I found that you can directly read from the computer's registry. I am not sure if this might trigger some anti-virus software or you will need an administrative account in order this to work, but as of the day of writing this piece of code will pull the list separator from the registry. `MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sList")` You can also use `HKCU` for all other region custom formatting on the computer.